# SpringBoot @Value annotation use

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I have been working on a scenario wherein I want to decrypt an entry in the application.yml .The value I want to encrypt, keep in yml file and then decrypt while the module comes up

```
@Value("${app.datasource.password}")
private String password;
```

I was trying to figure out how **@Value** works internally so that I could modify it to include this feature. If there is other way possible say by introducing custom annotation and AnnotationProcessor, it would also help.

Answer (score 3):

@Value Annotation just takes a Spring SPEL expression and evaluates it to set the result value for the annotated field.

For your use case you can write a Decrypter object and write a method to decrypt your data and use it as below.

```
@Value("#{passwordDecrypter.decrypt()}")
private String password;
```

Write a Bean for doing decryption

```
@Component
public class PasswordDecrypter{

    @Value("${app.datasource.password}")
    private String password; 

    public String decrypt(){
        // Return decrypted value
    }

}
```

Comment: This helps. However, is there  a simple annotation based approach which doesn't necessarily use @Value or other Spring annotations so that I can extend this solution to simple java programs

Comment: You can try this. https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot But remember that this is not provided from Spring.